# Write out AES key and IV in C#

Tags: c#, aes

Im trying to have c# generate a AES key and IV. But I am unable to find a way to have it write out the Key and IV.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            var iv = aes.GenerateIV();
            aes.GenerateKey();
            

        }

    }
```

When I assign a var to the generate method it gives an error of cannot assign void to an implicitly-type variable.
When i can it to a byte array it displays cannot implicitly convert type void to byte.

Comment: Maybe there's an IV property on your `aes` varaible? Like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.iv?view=net-6.0

Comment: Please show the code that fails along with the exact error message.

Comment: `var iv = aes.GenerateIV();` the method returns a void. That's the error and problem line.

Comment: the exact error is CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'byte[]'

Comment: Did you try accessing `Key` and `IV` properties of `aes`?

Comment: I hate to be the one to say RTFM, but the docs are rather clear.  Here's a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access `Key` and `IV` properties of `Aes` class to get values of Key and IV.

Aes Object when created by doing `Aes.Create`, will have IV and Key values available from it. You just need to retrieve them via Key and IV properties.

`Key` and `IV` properties are of type `byte[]` so you need to convert them to string to be able to see in text format.

Consider following code.

```
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
{
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    
    var key = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
    var iv = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);
     
    Console.WriteLine(key); 
    Console.WriteLine(iv);
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to call `GenerateIV` or `GenerateKey`, you get one when `Aes.Create` is called (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/generating-keys-for-encryption-and-decryption).

Comment: You are right @Flydog57.

Comment: `PaddingMode.Zeroes` in CBC mode? That is only useful if your data is really multiple of the block size all the time and if you want to implement your own padding.